# Application insight azure setAutoCollectExceptions(true) method issue

Tags: azure, error-handling, azure-application-insights

In Node js I'm using application insight of azure and enabled setAutoCollectExceptions(true) , But still it is not catching exceptions automatically .I need to use trackException manual method for that , But then what is use of setAutoCollectExceptions Why it is not catching exceptions automatically..???

This is my code

```
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING)
     .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
     .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)  
     .start();
```

I'm excpecting an exact reason why setAutoCollectExceptions is not working as excepted

Comment: You shouldn't be expected anything ^^ Also do you have any sample code where this is not working ad expected? That would be great to try to reproduce

Comment: @Thomas Check below code this is one js function  role is not defined here it will throw an error that error needs to be catched by application inside  by setAutoCollectExceptions(true) method .                                                                 const assignRole = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("role", role);
  return res.send(`${role} is assigned`);
};